# How to make a dynamic css with php by using a while?

Tags: php, css

I want to create a dynamic css that would take the data from the table of a database and then use that to create a series of buttons.

The table, named Buttons,  looks like this:

```
 Buttons

 PK     | Initials        | Color 
 ------------------------------------------
 1      | aaa             | #ff0000
 2      | bbb             | #00ff00
 3      | ccc             | #0000ff
```

This is how i create the buttons on my index.php, that works perfectly.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.php" />
    <?php

    $class = new Styleclass();
    $numbuttons = $class->ButCount();

    $i = 1;

    while ($i <= $numbuttons) {

        $initials = $styleapp->getInitBut($i);
        $color = $styleapp->getColorBut($i);

        echo '<button class="button'.$initials.'"> Sometext </button>';

        echo '</div>';

        $i = $i +1;
    }
  ?>
```

This is my Class.php (this name is an example)

```
  class Styleclass {

     public function ButCount (){
    $db = dbConn::getConnection();
    $query = 'SELECT COUNT(`PK`)
             FROM `Buttons`';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $nobut = $statement->fetchColumn(0);
    return $nobut;
}

public function getInitBut($pk) {
    $db = dbConn::getConnection();
    $query = 'SELECT `Initials`
                FROM `Buttons`
                WHERE (`PK` = :pk )';


    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':pk', $pk, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();
    $initials = $statement->fetchColumn(0);
    return $initials;
}

public function getColorBut($pk) {
    $db = dbConn::getConnection();
    $query = 'SELECT `Color`
                FROM `Buttons`
                WHERE (`PK` = :pk )';


    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':pk', $pk, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();
    $color = $statement->fetchColumn(0);
    return $color;
}
 }
```

And this is my css named style.php.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/css");
 ?>
<style type="text/css">


<?php

$class = new Styleclass();
    $numbuttons = $class->ButCount();

    $i = 1;

    while ($i <= $numbuttons) {

        $initials = $styleapp->getInitBut($i);
        $color = $styleapp->getColorBut($i);

    echo '.button'.$initials.' {';
    echo 'background-color : '.$color.';';
    echo 'color : #000;
padding : 16px;
font-size : 18px;
font-weight : bold;
font-family : Glegoo;
border-width : 1px 0 1px 0;
border-color : #000;
width : 200px;
cursor : pointer;
}';

        $i = $i +1;
    }
</style>
```

I have some jQuery linked with my buttons and it works, so I guess that my problem lies in my css, but I don't know how to make it works.

EDIT 1:

The output are a number of buttons of the same number as the rows in the table with the specified color.

Comment: you can create external css file and according to your 'Initials' define a .class in your css file, in your while loop change class name of your button.
echo '<button class="button'.$initials.'"> Sometext </button>';

Comment: What is the output of style.php? Give us an example

Comment: wasn't `$class = new StyleClass()`?

Comment: That is a mistake i made as I wrote the code here, it's not present in the original version.

Comment: FWIW, you'll spam the database with queries - considering you appear to be using the whole table worth of buttons anyway, you'd be better off just doing a `select Color,Initials from Buttons` and loop over that.